# ASP.NET MVC 4 + EF5 beta2 + DbGeography types + MiniProfiler throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an MVC 4 project using EF 5 Code First.  I am trying to install MiniProfile at no avail.

I pulled **MiniProfiler 2.0.1** and **MiniProfiler.EF 2.0.2** from NuGet, added the following on the Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize(); 
}
```

Immediately upon run, I get this error:

### *The provider did not return a DbSpatialServices instance.*

```
Line 58:   if (user != null)
Line 59:   {
Line 60:>>>    if (user.Places != null)
Line 61:       {
Line 62:            var place= user.Places .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a DbSpatialServices instance.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetDbSpatialDataReader(DbDataReader fromReader, String manifestToken) +62
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetSpatialDataReader(DbDataReader fromReader, String manifestToken) +101
   System.Data.Spatial.SpatialHelpers.CreateSpatialDataReader(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbDataReader reader) +70
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.CreateSpatialDataReader() +12
   System.Data.Common.Utils.Singleton`1.get_Value() +25
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.<GetSpatialPropertyValueWithErrorHandling>b__d(DbDataReader reader, Int32 column) +12
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +149
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetSpatialPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName, PrimitiveTypeKind spatialTypeKind) +269
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +942
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +239
   lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +221
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +163
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +88
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Merge(IEnumerable`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean setIsLoaded) +222
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption) +218
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption) +25
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load() +37
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad() +300
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty(TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject) +85
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item) +105
   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_C006B0EF9498157C70250EEE038C6BEADB719A2D5BDC4AA1FB567FB579AECEB5.get_Places() +55
   Project.Web.Controllers.PlaceController.Ribbon() in c:\Project\Project.Web\Controllers\PlaceController.cs:60
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +204
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +9
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +47
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +10
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +71
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1121
```

I have a couple of DbGeography types in my Places POCO.

```
public class Places 
{
    public Guid PlacesId { get; set; }
    ...
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Area { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have tried searching for that error but it does not show up in google anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in MiniProfiler, it should be reported at: http://community.miniprofiler.com

In particular profiling EF is very tricky, a lot of the work is done by wrapping every "provider" it uses. It seems that EFProfiledDbProviderFactory needs some special logic to locate, intercept and wrap the spatial services.

Comment: Having the same bug in EF6 -pre